# Extracting field values from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, storyq

I have a variable results which holds ResultView as shown below:
[image]

In turn StoryQ.Execution.Result IEnumerable will hold values:[image]

I need to extract text representation like " Story is Story". How can I achieve this. Could anyone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried to join the prefix and text with?

Comment: I hope asking a question with a research effort doesn't deserve a down vote as you did sir!

Comment: Actually I didnt down vote you, but thanks for making assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use select in conjunction with string format.

```
.Select( c => new {Story_Prefix_Text = string.Format("{0} {1}" ,c.Prefix, c.Text)})
```

or without lambda

```
from currentpath in collection
select new { Story_Prefix_Text = currentpath.Prefix + " " + currentpath.Text };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It didn't solve my problem though.  Appreciate your effort

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question just in case it would help somebody in future. 
The problem was solved by converting IEnumerable to List and then iterating through foreach loop. Code snippet is below:

```
var textFormat = ((IStepContainer)v).SelfAndAncestors().Reverse().ToList();
            foreach (var text in textFormat)
            {
                var StoryInText = text.Step.Prefix + " " + text.Step.Text;

            }
```